# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, xampp

I am using Mac OS X Lion version 10.8. I have MySQL installed through XAMPP. And I have added both mysql and the jdbc driver (5.1.22) to my classpath. The following simple code is not working:

```
package learning.database;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Simple {

Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";
return DriverManager.getConnection(url, "username", "password");
}

void createDatabase(String database, Connection conn) throws SQLException{
Statement stmt = null;
try {
stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate("drop database if exists "+database);
stmt.executeUpdate("create database "+database);
}finally {
if(null != stmt)
stmt.close();
}
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
String school = "school";
Classroom cr = new Classroom();
Connection conn = cr.getConnection();
cr.createDatabase(school, conn);
}
}
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:350)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2445)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2230)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:813)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:334)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
at learning.database.Classroom.getConnection(Classroom.java:43)
at learning.database.Simple.main(Simple.java:33)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:432)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:218)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:259)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300)
... 16 more
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Thanks to Max and Yogendra for posting.
The problem turned out to have been my XAMPP configuration. To fix it, I did as follows:

```
-   sudo vi /Applications/XAMPP/etc/my.cnf 
⁃   scroll down to `skip-networking`
⁃   comment it out by changing it to `#skip-networking`
⁃   save the changes.
⁃   restart mysql from XAMPP Console
```

Then I run my code and everything is fine!

Answer (score 0):

Please use mysql-connector-java-5.1.10-bin.jar or above for MySQL database. And following are correct code. Change import statement from jdbc. Eg. import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection; and import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;
instead of 
import java.sql.Connection; and import java.sql.Statement;

You need to load class driver for MySQL using Class.forName(driver). use following code it will work.

```
            Connection conn = null;
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
            String dbName = "databaseName";
            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            String userName = "root";
            String password = "root";
            try
            {
                    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
                    conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url
                                    + dbName, userName, password);
                    Statement stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: This does not work. I get the same error.

Comment: Class.forName(driver).newInstance(); will load the driver and in your code this statement is missing.