# No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://192.168.10.161/testdb

Tags: hibernate, jsp

i created a jsp hibernate application in order store the values entered in jsp to database using hibernate
i am using toad for my sql as data base and it is throwing the following error
plz hep me
192.168.10.161 is a system in network which consist of toad
 No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://192.168.10.161/testdb

Comment: May have a look at: [No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/ (Stackoverflow)][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590314/no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost

Comment: Are you using tomcat, jboss, glassfish...?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing because of there is no  `MySql JDBC Driver` present in your project libraries.
Add [MySql JDBC Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-5.1.25.zip/from/http://cdn.mysql.com/) in your project libraries.
I hope it will work.